# PC Game: Flaming skull skeletons as enemies

Tags: story-identification, video-games, medieval

I played this game at least 16 years ago... It has to be either from the late 90s or early 2000s. It has third-person gameplay.

I don't remember what the story was actually about (it had a fantasy medieval kind of setting though), but IIRC the opening scene had a village being attacking at night by an army of skeletons with flaming skulls (I remember there's a particular close-up one the face of one of them).

The protagonist gets captured and imprisoned in a castle's dungeon, from which he has to escape and fight them. You are a dude with dark hair and a sword IIRC.

Comment: Any idea what platform you may have played this on? Also what was the gameplay type? Top down, sideways scroller, isometric?

Comment: I played this on the PC. IIRC, it had a third person type camera similar to the PS2 GTA games.

Comment: Could it be one of the "The Dark Eye"/"Realms of Arkania" RPGs. Haven't found anything regarding flaming skulls though, but I remember playing an RPG like this at this time and I was also playing The Dark Eye, or rather the German Das schwarze Auge.

Comment: Extremely late reply, I apologize! But sadly that's not it... I guess I'll never get to find it... must've been one of those really rare forgettable games.

Comment: Was it Doom 1993 ? I'm also trying to find a similar pc game as yours :(

Comment: Diablo perhaps?

Comment: It sounds like the opening trailer of Diablo 2. Could that be it?

Comment: My first thought was Hexen but it was first person and I may be thinking of the flaming skulls from Doom or Quake.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like *Crusaders of Might and Magic*, a medieval fantasy-themed game for PC and PlayStation from 1999. It is a third-person action sword-wielding and magic-shooting game with a black haired dude and a sword.

The intro cinematic shows a village attacked at night by an army of skeletons, though they do not have flaming skulls, but they do have flaming red eyes. There are two skull close-up scenes in it. Finally, the protagonist does get captured, starting the game from a prison cell. Fits pretty closely with your description.

Answer (score 4):

It may be Diablo 2. It fits the time line since the game came out in 2000. The opening cinematic does contain a village being attacked by skeletons jumping out of fire

(check at the 4m30s mark).
It's 3D, in a medival setting.

I can't tell you how the game start since the opening gave me nightmares of flaming sketons and so I never played it.

Comment: top down / third person